# Securing jQuery AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension which will be sending data via an AJAX request using jQuery. I need to ensure though that only the logged in user has send the request. This might not be the right approach trying to secure the AJAX request itself so any advice is appriciated.

Comment: It's not possible to secure an ajax request from the client-side alone.

Comment: @hasanain what relevance does that have to determining if user is logged in or not?

Comment: You have to do the check on the server. When they login, you set a cookie with a random string. Then check for this cookie value when they send later requests.

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please mark the best answer as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot secure Ajax requests on client side as every one can request to your APIs if it's included in your JS.
but there are some workarounds which you can choose to have more secure interact with your server:

- you can send encrypted data
- you can also obfuscate your code to make it much harder to read
- use SSL to protect data from snoopers

**EDIT:**
as you mentioned if you want to make sure a user is logged in to do something you can use encrypted cookie and a token as mentioned in another answer. but if you want to prevent requests and not rejecting them maybe above solutions will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, when the user logs in, you need to set a cookie that contains some sort of authentication token or session ID (usually some unpredictable string of characters) that is also stored on your server.

Your Ajax request can then include that authentication token from the current browser's cookie as a parameter of the ajax call and your server can then authenticate that the token belongs to a legitimate user.

If the user is not logged in, there will be no cookie and thus no token.